# SQL - Mudar Nomes de Campos dentro de uma Coluna

Tags: sql

Boas, tenho uma duvida, eu tenho por exemplo uma coluna chamada "Categorias" 
e dentro dessa coluna tenho diversos campos (categorias) e queria alterar o nome desses campos.

Por exemplo "coluna categorias" - e dentro dela tenho varias categorias com os seguintes nomes : RMS-FUTEBOL ; RMS-BASQUET ; RMS-TENIS; RMS-BADMITON ; (...);
e queria alterar esses nomes dentro dessa coluna para: Futebol; Basquet; Tenis; Badminton , e por ai fora.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Tenho uma ideia que por update talvez seja possivel fazer mas não estou a ver como alterar diversos nomes de campos dentro da mesma coluna agredecia uma ajuda com este exemplo que dei obrigado.L

Comment: Qual o banco de dados que você usa? Todas as colunas começam com RMS ou tem variação?

Comment: Uso SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO. Todas teem variaçao por exemplo uma é RMS-FUTEBOL , Outra é TRA-ANDEBOL o que eu quero apenas e reduzir esse texto para FUTEBOL ANDEBOL entre outros.

Coluna "Categoria" --> Campos/Valores dentro coluna categoria "RMS-FUTEBOL" , "TRA-ANDEBOL", (...) entre outras categorias.

Não quero mudar nome de coluna mas sim dos campos/valores que estão dentro dessa coluna se é que me estou a explicar bem.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode rodar esses `UPDATE`s:

```
UPDATE sua_tabela SET categorias = 'Futebol' WHERE categorias = 'RMS-FUTEBOL';
UPDATE sua_tabela SET categorias = 'Basquet' WHERE categorias = 'RMS-BASQUET';
UPDATE sua_tabela SET categorias = 'Tenis' WHERE categorias = 'RMS-TENIS';
UPDATE sua_tabela SET categorias = 'Badminton' WHERE categorias = 'RMS-BADMITON';
```

Para verificar se ainda falta algo a ser alterado:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categorias FROM sua_tabela WHERE categorias LIKE 'RMS-%';
```

Ou então, para ver todas as categorias e conferir se não há nenhuma errada:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categorias FROM sua_tabela;
```

Em todos esses casos `sua_tabela` é o nome da tabela que tem a coluna `categorias`.

Comment: obg victor irei experimentar mais logo e depois darei o feedback.